# Is SceneKit node rotation cumulative

Tags: scenekit

What happens if i a make a rotation on a scenekit node object this way:

```
node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, M_PI_2)
```

Does it adds PI/2 to existing rotation or does it set object angle to PI/2?

In other words what happens if i call twice this line:

```
node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, M_PI_2)
```

Does it rotate to PI/2 or PI ?

I have the same question for node.eulerAngles property

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

none of the `SCNNode` properties regarding transforms is "cumulative", just like the `transform` of a `CALayer` for instance. To combine transforms you'll want to use utils such as [SCNMatrix4Rotate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/1409659-scnmatrix4rotate).

Answer (score 0):

While I'll never argue with what is in SceneKit with mnuages (I think he works on it at Apple), I will contend that he's taken your question too literally.

If you are looking for cumulative rotation, it is available in SceneKit, if you know how much rotation you want. You can use the two `rotateBy` SCNActions.

They are :

[rotateBy(x:y:z:duration:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnaction/1523522-rotateby)

and:

[rotate(by:around:duration:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnaction/1523805-rotate)

Both of these, applied repeatedly, will cumulatively add to the rotation of your object.